# How to update a single value with laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello i want to update a single value on another table using laravel. This is the code i have done until now but doesnt seem to work:

```php
$amount = Product::findorFail($request->products[$i]);
$total_value = $request->amount[$i] + $amount->amount;
$amount->update(['amount', $total_value]);
dd($total_value);
```

with `dd` i see that the result is correct but the update function is not, the query im trying to make is

`update table set amount=x where id=y`

Comment: change it to $amount->update(['amount'=>$total_value]);

Comment: Or also `$amount->amount = $total_amount; $amount->save() ;`

Comment: @StewieSWS yes that works but i have to use the `update` function

Comment: Eloquent also has an `increment` function; `$product->increment('amount', '100')` will add 100 to `amount`'s current value. This has the bonus of being safe if multiple users are working on the same `$product` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple choices. The shortes are:

```php
$amount->update(['amount'=> $amount->amount + request->amount[$i]]);
```

**or**

```php
Product::findorFail($request->products[$i])->increment('amount', $request->amount[$i]);
```

Comment: What's the point of writing an answer if it already have been answered in comments 15 min ago?

Answer (score -1):

you could change your code like below

```php
$amount = Product::findorFail($request->products[$i]);
$total_value = $request->amount[$i] + $amount->amount;
$amount->amount=$total_value;
$amount->update();
```

or as mentioned in comments you could use eloquent increment function